# Revert merge of master to feature branch

Tags: git

I have a tracking branch to which I merged my master branch. There were conflicts that I fixed, committed and pushed. Now I need to revert that merge. How do I do it? I tried checking log, but obviously the history from master is now in the feature branch. Is there any hope?

Comment: There's always hope using source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, it looks like you want to revert on your feature branch the merge commit that merged from your master branch.

You can do this in 2 ways, one which is more safe.

1. `git revert -m <parent_index> HEAD`

To get the parent index, run `git show <merge commit SHA1>` and see the index (1-based) of the commit you want to revert to.

1. `git reset --hard <feature branch SHA1>`

This isn't the better option because it resets your history and you won't be able to get back to the merge commit even if you wanted to.

I suggest using the first one because you get to keep track of the merge commit, in case you want to see how you merged something later on.

Comment: git show <merge commit SHA1> returns the same information set as git log. What I found confusing is the fact of two parent keys being present. In the end I have used git revert -m 1 <SHA of commit>. And I'm back to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard <sha of last commit of feature branch>
```

We consider ur move is a merge commit. It will revert to feature branch and trash the merge commit.